# This Code should return Product Title, But instead of title, I am getting "None" in return

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to make a price tracker for Amazon by viewing a youtube tutorial, I am new to python and web scraping, Somehow I wrote this code and It should return Product name, But Instead its giving me "None" as an output, Can you please help me with this?

I tried with different URL's still its not working.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Nike-Rival-Track-Field-Shoes/dp/B07HYNB7VV/'

headers = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/57.36 (HTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.30.100 Safari/537.4'}

page =requests.get(URL,headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

title = soup.find(id="productTitle")

print(title)import requests
```

Comment: Amazon is probably rejecting your request.  They don't like being scraped.

Comment: Thanks for helping sir, I tried it with Flipkart, eBay and few other URL's too, Still getting the same output. Can you suggest me a good website to put in URL field?

Comment: Print the status_code and text property of your page, Amazon is rejecting your automated (non-browser) request, as Chris suggested. `Sorry, we just need to make sure you\'re not a robot. For best results, please make sure your browser is accepting cookies.`. You would need to try a site that has no such checks.

Comment: Yes, I tried with few sites but for every site, this is giving me "None" as an output.

Answer (score 1):

I was inspecting the returned HTML, and realized that Amazon sends a (somewhat malformed?) HTML that trips the default `html.parser`, but using `lxml` I was able to scrape title just fine.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

def make_soup(url: str) -> BeautifulSoup:
    res = requests.get(url, headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0'
    })
    res.raise_for_status()
    return BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

def parse_product_page(soup: BeautifulSoup) -> dict:
    title = soup.select_one('#productTitle').text.strip()
    return {
        'title': title
    }

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = 'https://www.amazon.com/Nike-Rival-Track-Field-Shoes/dp/B07HYNB7VV/'
    soup = make_soup(url)
    info = parse_product_page(soup)
    print(info)
```

output:

```
{'title': "Nike Men's Zoom Rival M 9 Track and Field Shoes"}
```

Comment: I used **html5lib** and it turned out to be fine for me as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your locator more specific using `.select()`. You need to change the parser as well.

Try this instead:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Nike-Rival-Track-Field-Shoes/dp/B07HYNB7VV/'

page = requests.get(URL,headers={"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'lxml') #make sure you use "lxml' or "html5lib" parser instead of "html.parser"
title = soup.select_one("h1 > #productTitle").get_text(strip=True)
print(title)
```

Output:

```
Nike Men's Zoom Rival M 9 Track and Field Shoes
```

Comment: Not really, there's only a single element with `id="productTitle"`.

Answer (score -1):

Bot detection is pretty pervasive these days.  No major site with any data worth mining, especially retail, is going to let you use requests on their site.

You're going to have to at the very least use Selenium / ChromeDriver to get a response from any reputable site.  Even then if they use something like Distil for bot detection they will stop even Selenium.

Try a less popular site with Selenium, and you will get data back.

Comment: What? Where did you get your information? That is extremely false information and do not go around giving this out as an answer... You do not need to use `Selenium`... maybe on extremely rare cases where these is to much `javascript` to re-create.